# Core Data Mac OS X app and compatibilty with OS X 10.7

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data

Hello i have created a Simple Application with Core Data and OS X 10.8, it's the simple template that xcode create, but if i change the Base SDK to 10.7 xcode give me this error on this method in App Controller:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator) {
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [self managedObjectModel];
if (!mom) {
    NSLog(@"%@:%@ No model to generate a store from", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return nil;
}

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *applicationFilesDirectory = [self applicationFilesDirectory];
NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *properties = [applicationFilesDirectory resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLIsDirectoryKey] error:&error];

if (!properties) {
    BOOL ok = NO;
    if ([error code] == NSFileReadNoSuchFileError) {
        ok = [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[applicationFilesDirectory path] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    }
    if (!ok) {
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
} else {
    if (![properties[NSURLIsDirectoryKey] boolValue]) {
        // Customize and localize this error.
        NSString *failureDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expected a folder to store application data, found a file (%@).", [applicationFilesDirectory path]];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dict setValue:failureDescription forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:101 userInfo:dict];

        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
}

NSURL *url = [applicationFilesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SimpleApp.storedata"];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSXMLStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error]) {
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    return nil;
}
_persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

i receive this error:

[image]

how i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not a problem with Core Data, but this is having to do with [object subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). In order for these literals to work correctly, your SDK needs to be at least OS X 10.8 or iOS 6.

If there is no other way, you can still use subscripting and keep your SDK to 10.7 by adding a stub header to a category on NSObject that implements the required methods. You can see one such example [here](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/using-subscripting-with-Xcode-4_4-and-iOS-4_3/). I'd advise keeping your SDK on 10.8, however.

Comment: So how i can fix it to run on 10.7?

Comment: Yes, it will be able to. This is syntactical sugar, not relating to OS.